# Displaying views that contain 'partial'/'nested' widgets in EXTjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm having trouble understanding how I need to define and use the MVC model for my test EXTjs4 app. Consider the following structure.

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Cards', 'Fourscrum'],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            defaults: { flex: 1 },
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch',
            },
            items:
            [
                Ext.widget('Fourscrum')
            ]
        });
```

Controller:

Cards.js

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Cards', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        stores: ['BacklogCards', 'InprogressCards', 'ReviewCards', 'DoneCards', 'Cards', 'Priorities', 'Sizes'],
        models: ['Card', 'Priority', 'Size'],
        views: ['card.List', 'priority.prioritycombo', 'card.Edit'],
```

Fourscrum.js

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Fourscrum', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['BacklogCards', 'InprogressCards', 'ReviewCards', 'DoneCards', 'Cards', 'Priorities', 'Sizes'],
    models: ['Card', 'Priority', 'Size'],
    views: ['scrum.Fourscrum', 'card.List'],
```

view.scrum.Fourscrum.js

```
Ext.define('AM.view.scrum.Fourscrum', {   // *** Variable
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Fourscrum',       // *** Variable

    width: 400,
    height: 300,

    layout: 'column',

    title: 'Scrum',                  // *** Variable
    items:
    [
        Ext.widget('cardlist',
        {
            alias: 'widget.backlogcardlist',
            title: "Backlog",
            store: 'BacklogCards'
        }),
        Ext.widget('cardlist',
        {
            alias: 'widget.backlogcardlist',
            title: "Backlog",
            store: 'BacklogCards'
        }),
        Ext.widget('cardlist',
        {
            alias: 'widget.inprogresscardlist',
            title: "In Progress",
            store: "InprogressCards"
        }),
        Ext.widget('cardlist',
        {
            alias: 'widget.reviewcardlist',
            title: "Review",
            store: "ReviewCards"
        }),
        Ext.widget('cardlist',
        {
            alias: 'widget.donecardlist',
            title: "Done",
            store: "DoneCards"
        })
    ]

});
```

My ideal structure for this app is as follows:

Viewport defined (inside app.js)

which contains a Fourscrum.js view (which is just a panel)

which contains 4 different List.js views (which are just grids).

Trying to accomplish this, I currently get a few errors when i start messing with the above code:

1. Item undefined
2. namespace undefined

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

PS. I can get this example to work if I replace my 'cardlist' widgets with panels directly defined in the Fourscrum view.

PPS. This also works properly if I forego the Fourscrum container panel all together :(

EDIT:

I felt my explanation was a little unclear so I've uploaded an image to help describe the program. I'm not sure where I need to define the stores, models, and views with this nested structure. So I've repeated it in both controllers. I hope that's not what is causing the problem.

[image]

EDIT2:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.card.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.cardlist',

    //title: 'List',
    //store: 'Cards',


    //multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'ddzone',
            dropGroup: 'ddzone'
        }
    },
    //            selType: 'cellmodel',
    //            plugins: [
    //                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    //                    clicksToEdit: 1
    //                })
    //            ],

    columns: [
        {
            header: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'external_id',
            field: 'textfield',
            width: 30
        },
        {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            field: 'textfield',
            width: 150
        },
        {
            header: 'Priority',
            dataIndex: 'priority_id',
            renderer: function (value) {
                var display = '';
                Ext.data.StoreManager.get("Priorities").each(function (rec) {
                    if (rec.get('id') === value) {
                        display = rec.get('short_name');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return display;
            },
            width: 60,
            field: { xtype: 'PriorityCombo' }
        },
        {
            header: 'Size',
            dataIndex: 'size_id',
            renderer: function (value) {
                var display = '';
                Ext.data.StoreManager.get("Sizes").each(function (rec) {
                    if (rec.get('id') === value) {
                        display = rec.get('short_name');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return display;
            },
            width: 60
        },
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 16,
            items: [{
                icon: 'Styles/Images/zoom.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
                tooltip: 'Zoom In',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    alert("Edit " + rec.get('name'));
                }
            }]
        }
    ]

});
```

Comment: What tool did you use to get that nice diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see a big problem in your code (if you pasted all of it). 
In your view definitions if you are extending Ext components you MUST have the following function  that ends in the callParent method like below.

```
initComponent: function() {
  this.items = this.buildMyItems();  

  this.callParent(arguments);    
},

buildMyItems: function(){
  //my code
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the additional response. I'm going to try this and your baby steps suggestion from down below ^_^

Comment: I admit it will take a while to get back into it ^_^ Because I wasn't getting any responses, I sort of gave up on EXTjs and just completed this little test with MVC3 and JQuery

Comment: Got it :) If you don't mind me asking - how did you learn EXTjs? I'm no expert in jquery but I can at least figure out a couple ways to get around the problems I encounter when coding - but with extjs, I just feel helpless.

Comment: I know exactly how you feel. ExtJS API is very large and it takes some time to to learn it and gain expertise. However, I feel there is really no other library complete enough to build applications (not a web page) with a plethora of ready made widgets.

Comment: Here are some of the learning resources:  1. API Docs on sencha.com, read the guides on the front page http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/ . 2. Reread the guides again :).  3. Learning center : http://www.sencha.com/learn/extjs/?4x especially the MVC guides by Tommy Mainz 4. Go over Examples, open the source! 5. Saki examples.extjs.eu is awesome! he has examples of his own (but they r still 3x). 6. Never close the API page, actually read it, use the 'source' links to read the source. 7. Sencha Forums search-post-search... 8. Realize that everything is overridable and customizable, everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Robodude,
According to the Class guide on Sencha.com all widgets must be contained in properly named class files. I don't think you can simultaneously define and create your widgets in the panel definition. 
Split out your definitions from the panel config. Also dont forget to enable the auto loader:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});
```

Comment: Hmm... Ok although I don't exactly know how to do that. Would those definition js files go into the models folder? Is there a specific format for that when it goes in there?

Comment: Yes, its in the guide, you are very close.

Comment: Sorry man :( I'm still pretty lost. I don't see where I'm failing to put them in a properly named class file. I'm updating the original question with my widget.cardlist.

Comment: OK, so let me ask u a series of questions:
1. Are u using Firefox and if so can u see in the script tab if all of your files that u expect to load are loaded? Are there any 404 or 500 errors in the Net tab?     <br/>
2. I see some syntax issues like extra commas. Can you strip down the code to just the viewport and say one panel, then add one thing at a time until you can see which last part is failing? Baby steps :)

Comment: Also, here is the file structure that Sencha recommends for MVC: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture